# 2006 honda civic green key flash, recently jumped started and replaced battery will start but then it dies

Tags: honda, civic, security

Ok i have read several articles on this problem and have concluded that most likely i need to reprogram my car key to the car or emobilizer. My question is. Is it possible for me to reprogram it myself with out taking it to the dealership? I have like no money to pay for any repairs let alone the costly ones from dealerships so please help me if you can because right now i have no car to drive and no money. If it is possible to reprogram the key myself please explain a step by step guid i can follow in order to do it myself. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have a second key (which hopefully works)?

Comment: Looking online, I'm only seeing where a key requires diagnostic equipment to enable programming of the key if the immobilizer (green flashing key) is activated.